# Using jQuery jcrop plugin to upload photo from webcam is wrong size.?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jcrop

I am trying to take a photo with a webcam, crop it using jcrop jquery library, and upload the cropped photo to a server. Regardless of the size of the thumbnail, it always ends up with a width of 300 pixels and a height of 150 pixels.

For the webcam photo capture, I've been using a jQuery webcam plugin: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/. I've also tried one that uses getusermedia https://github.com/MrSwitch/jquery.getUserMedia.js.

Uploading just the webcam snaptshot works correctly and is the expected size.

My javascript:

```
$('#canvas').Jcrop({
        boxWidth: 320,
        boxHeight: 240,
        onChange:   updatePreview,
        onSelect:   updatePreview,
        addClass: 'jcrop-dark',
        aspectRatio : 1},function(){
    jcrop_api = this;
 });

 function showPreview(coords)
{
    var rx = 100 / coords.w;
    var ry = 100 / coords.h;

    $('#preview').css({
        width: Math.round(rx * 320) + 'px',
        height: Math.round(ry * 240) + 'px',
        marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * coords.x) + 'px',
        marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * coords.y) + 'px'
    });
}

function updatePreview(c) {
    if(parseInt(c.w) > 0) {
        // Show image preview
        var imageObj = $("#canvas")[0];
        var canvas = $("#preview")[0];
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.drawImage(imageObj, c.x, c.y, c.w, c.h, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
};
$('#save').click(function(){
    var imgData = document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL();
    var postStr = "img=" + encodeURIComponent(imgData);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{{ path('photo_upload') }}',
        data: postStr,
        async: false,
        processData: false,
        error: function(){
            $('.hero-unit').prepend('<div class="alert alert-error">The photo could not be uploaded.<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button></div>');
        }
    });
});
```

Simple Test PHP

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'photos/');
$img = $_POST['img'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR  . 'photo.png';
$fp = fopen($file, 'wb');
$success=fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="webcam"></div>
<a href="javascript:webcam.capture();changeFilter();void(0);">Take a picture instantly</a>
<canvas id="canvas" height="240" width="320"></canvas>
<canvas id="preview" style="width:300px;height:300px;overflow:hidden;"></canvas>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" id="save">Save Photo</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that code exactly what you are trying to use?

My guess would be you have a canvas which is still at the default size (which just happens to be 300x150) which is causing that to be the image that is sent to your server and saved.

Also, why do you have your preview with a style width and height instead of setting the actual width and height?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Setting the width and height directly worked. I did have some css setting the sizes of things as well plus the actual webcam capture code that I excluded. Guess it wasn't able to determine the size based off of the css styling.

Comment: Just so you know, a canvas' width and height attribute control it's "drawing" size (as well as it's physical size). Setting the CSS size overrides the physical size, but not the drawing size (so if your canvas is 300x150 and you set the CSS to 300x300, it just stretches to show it at that size, same as an image).